# What are the uses for Linq's GroupBy method with resultselector overload?

Tags: c#, linq

On MSDN I found the following overload of the Enumerable.GroupBy method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector)
```

along with the following example:

```
    List<Pet> petsList =
    new List<Pet>{ new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8.3 },
                   new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4.9 },
                   new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1.5 },
                   new Pet { Name="Daisy", Age=4.3 } };

    var query = petsList.GroupBy(
    pet => Math.Floor(pet.Age), //keySelector
    pet => pet.Age,             //elementSelector
    (baseAge, ages) => new      //resultSelector
    {
        Key = baseAge,
        Count = ages.Count(),
        Min = ages.Min(),
        Max = ages.Max()
    });
```

Although I understand how this code works, I can't think of a practical use of it. As I see it now, this will return an `Enumerable` with elements of the anonymous type defined in the end of the code. But why would a **GroupBy** method, return an enumerable that's not divided in groups? Can't the same be accomplished by using Select, OrderBy etc.? Or is the main purpose of this overload to define a `Dictionary` yourself as part of the `TResult`?

Comment: It's there so you can avoid `.GroupBy(...).Select(...)`, and avoid creating `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects in the process, which will just get immediately projected into something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following two queries will produce the same results.

```
var queryA = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

var queryB = source
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id, (key, g) => new { Id = key, Count = g.Count() });
```

The difference is that the first query has to instantiate an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` per group, while the second query does not. You should prefer `queryB` in this case.

Comment: Accepted this answer because of the clear example, I didn't think about the useless IGrouping that's made in those specific cases, thanks!

Comment: I was thinking about this today and did the two queries `.ToString()` today, it actually produces exactly the same sql. The 2nd method still looks more elegant of course (at the cost of readability though)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck That's only the case when `source` is `IQueryable<T>`. If `source` is `IEnumerable<T>`, the last paragraph of my answer applies.

Comment: I was curious about the last paragraph and the code seems to not confirm that - the Lookup is created first and then resultSelector is applied, so I don't see how it would be different from applying Select method separately. Do I miss something? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2382

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does nothing that can't be done with a `Select()`. We could even implement it as:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
  return source.GroupBy(keySelector, elementSelector).Select(grp => resultSelector(grp.Key, grp));
}

/* Repeat in Queryable for IQueryable */
```

But, firstly, it isn't implemented this way, and this relatively common case is dealt with more efficiently.

Secondly, and I suspect a bigger influence (but can't of course say for sure) is that the `IQueryable` version is analogous to many SQL group constructions. Indeed, for the most part with SQL's `GROUP BY` we must use aggregate functions with those selected items we don't include in the `GROUP BY`. Consider:

```
SELECT FLOOR(age), COUNT(ALL age), MIN(age), MAX(age)
FROM Pets
GROUP BY FLOOR(age)
```

Which is pretty much equivalent to the list-based operation in the example you quote.

So it makes sense to have those overloads of `Queryable.GroupBy()` that take a `resultSelector` parameter, and when they are in `Queryable` acting on `IQueryable` then the corresponding method has to be in `Enumerable` acting on `IEnumerable`.